# In Blazor App, Change default index razor component to another

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am created one new Blazor App. In that below folder structure..

[image]

And _Host.cshtml, it has `@page "/"`... Even changed to `@page "/QuizViewer"` 
it shows index page contents.. It is not shwoing QuizViewer Page contents. Can someone help. In the Index page i have @page "/"..**
It shows like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***After Posted..** i tried multiple times.. and i found the answer. Once i delete Index.razor file and change QuizViewer razor first line as @page "/" from @page "/QuizViewer" It started working.***